# Changing default color and removing legend in geom_density2d() plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

In the code below, how do I remove the 2nd legend (for alpha levels, I think) and change the default blue color to, say, red?

```
suppressMessages(library(ggmap))
data(crime)
houston.map <- get_map(location = geocode("Houston"),
                       zoom = 14)
ggmap(houston.map, extent = "device", legend = "topleft") +
  stat_density2d(data = crime,
                 aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..),
                 size = 2,
                 bins = 10,
                 geom = "polygon") +
  labs(fill = "Density")
```

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `guides` layer to remove the second legend by specifying `alpha` as `FALSE` and you can change the colour scale with `scale_fill_gradient` as I've done below:

```
ggmap(houston.map, extent = "device", legend = "topleft") +
  stat_density2d(data = crime,
                 aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..),
                 size = 2,
                 bins = 10,
                 geom = "polygon") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#333333", high = "#cc0000") +
  labs(fill = "Density") +
  guides(alpha = F)
```

Comment: `scale_fill_gradient()`works great, but`legend.position = "none"`removes both legends (the previous answer works there). Thanks a lot. By the way, how do I accept both answers?

Comment: Ah, I misread the question with regards to the legend. You can only accept one answer. Glad it helped :)

Comment: I changed my answer to include the `guides` layer instead of `theme`

Answer (score 1):

Adding `guides(alpha = F)` removes that legend.

```
suppressMessages(library(ggmap))
data(crime)
houston.map <- get_map(location = geocode("Houston"),
                       zoom = 14)
ggmap(houston.map, extent = "device", legend = "topleft") +
  stat_density2d(data = crime,
                 aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..),
                 size = 2,
                 bins = 10,
                 geom = "polygon") +
  guides(alpha = F) + 
  labs(fill = "Density")
```